# Embedding Jetty 9 - where is jetty-all.jar?

Tags: java, jetty

I'm trying to embed Jetty 9 in my project, and the tutorial at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/advanced-embedding.html#jetty-helloworld suggests I need a file called "jetty-all.jar", but I can't seem to find this in the download distribution.  Where do I get it from?  I'm not using maven.

Comment: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/aggregate/jetty-all/

Comment: [jetty-all does not, and cannot, contain all of jetty](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg06030.html).  It is also 100% inappropriate to use as a dependency in any build.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Why, therefore, does the tutorial suggest using it as such?

Comment: The tutorial uses it for command line examples, for learning about jetty, not for running anything beyond a simple single java class environment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found it in maven repo with a different version:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/aggregate/jetty-all/9.0.4.v20130625/jetty-all-9.0.4.v20130625.jar

[The Search Engine for The Central Repository](http://search.maven.org) may helps you find jar files even you don't use maven

Comment: jetty-all was mis-named, it should have been called jetty-tutorial for it's role, ONLY for documentation.   The jetty-all jar and concept has been completely removed Jetty 10+.