# Setting up Vaadin 10+ with Jetty 9.4.19 v20190610

Tags: java, frameworks, jetty, vaadin

I'm trying to integrate into a NO MAVEN STANDALONE JAVA APP, Vaadin Framework with latest version of Jetty Uber jar. I've search how it could be done, and I found a solution:

```
WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
context.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(webRootUri));
context.setContextPath(contextPath);
context.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern", ".*");
context.setConfigurationDiscovered(true);
context.setConfigurations(new Configuration[]{
                new AnnotationConfiguration(),
                new WebInfConfiguration(),
                new WebXmlConfiguration(),
                new MetaInfConfiguration(),
                new FragmentConfiguration(),
                new EnvConfiguration(),
                new PlusConfiguration(),
                new JettyWebXmlConfiguration()
        });
context.getServletContext().setExtendedListenerTypes(true);
context.addEventListener(new ServletContextListeners());
```

(setting WebAppContext programmatically or with web.xml file), but what I see on browser is something without default theme styling and the components looks awful. What am I trying to do is to reuse code from backend standalone app and not rewrite again a new app for web.

If someone tried this in the past and found a solution, can be kind and write a tutorial ?

Comment: What do you mean with "latest version of Jetty Uber jar"?  (there's no such thing on the Jetty side)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt , I refer to this http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/aggregate/jetty-all/

Comment: See https://www.eclipse.org/lists/jetty-users/msg06030.html

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010150/embedding-jetty-9-where-is-jetty-all-jar